# Azure AD B2C Phone OTP verification

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication, identity-experience-framework

We have a requirement wherein admin users should be able to login to an app and validate the customer's phone number through OTP.
We intend to use the profile edit policy so that when an admin logs in clicks on edit he can update the phone number to a customer's and get it validated. Again when a new customer's number needs to be validated, the admin would update his phone number to validate the new number. Same applies for email validation as well. Customer's don't have access to the app so would be depending on the admin.
Is this approach right? Is there any limitation in B2C as to how many times in a day an MFA number can be updated?

Comment: Seems like an odd repurposing of profile edit, but would function. There are limits on how many OTPs can be sent from a single IP in a certain time period. We do not disclose that publicly as normal usage by actual end users wouldn’t hit those limits. If you use a 3rd party MFA provider, you could get around that. Also this type of process can create a bad habit of users thinking it’s OK to provide an OTP code to a bad actor over the phone, which ultimately compromises their account. If there is some other process where the customer performs the action, it’s preferable.

Comment: Why not send the customer an invite link to their email and have them set up their own account?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The customers don't have a digital identity but walked into a store and the admins need to validate their number/email via OTP functionality of AAD B2C.

Comment: How about having the customer scan a QR code and they themselves going through a flow which verifies their number? Presuming you want to save this number somewhere?

Comment: Wow, this seems interesting. But how do we implement it? Is there any sample present in GitHub?